# Multiplayer Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm creating a game using node and socket. How can i create a unified count down user countdown timer that don't reset when user refresh the browser. Every 60 seconds the users bids then after 60 seconds i should get all the winner. I'm really having a hard time on the server side countdown timer.

I used this code:

```
var countdown = 60;
setInterval(function() {
    countdown--;
    io.sockets.emit('timer', { countdown: countdown });
}, 1000);
```

but each time the user connect the timer restart from the start

Comment: if its in node, why is it tagged php as well?

Comment: Post the relevant code that you've tried, so that people can help you.

Comment: i used this code..var countdown = 60;
setInterval(function() {
 countdown--;
 
 io.sockets.emit('timer', { countdown: countdown });
}, 1000); but each time the user connect it restart the timer to start

Comment: You didn't post *where* that code is. Without that, we can't tell you why it resets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies or session to keep the time. This way when the user refreshes, they will not be resetting the count.

Javascript will reset the count each time because each one of them are considered as a new request.

Use cookies or sessions.

Comment: but how about multi user? when there is a new user that connects the time will be reset right?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out your problem. if u put the Interval loop in the function that triggers when users connect it will run all over again. but if you put it outside the connect event then u will be fine.
like instead of doing

```
io.on("connection", function (sockets){
    var countdown = 60;
setInterval(function() {
countdown--;
io.sockets.emit('timer', { countdown: countdown });
 }, 1000);
});
```

## you would do it like this

```
var countdown = 60;
setInterval(function() {
countdown--;
io.emit('timer', { countdown: countdown });
 }, 1000);

//can come after or before timer function
io.on("connection", function(sockets){
//your code
});
```

doing this prevents the time from refreshing when the user joins.